# Ruby array only storing last value, not all values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops

I have a Ruby app with Products and Categories.

I would like to have a category index page that displays 1 product photo for each category.

Right now, it shows the **last** product photo for all categories. (So, with 16 categories, it shows the product photo for category 16 on every category.)

I think I need to fix how I store or call the Products array. How do I do that?

Code --

in categories_controller.rb

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all.order('name ASC')
  @products = []

  @categories.each do |category|
    @products = Product.where(category_id: category.id).take(1)
  end
end
```

in categories/index.html.erb

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(product.image), category %>
    <% end %>
  <%= link_to category.name, category %>
  <%= category.description %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `index` action, change the line:

```
@products = Product.where(category_id: category.id).take(1)
```

To:

```
@products << Product.where(category_id: category.id).take(1)
```

**UPDATE:**

Since `take(1)` will return an object in array, you need to simply change it to:

```
@products << Product.where(category_id: category.id).take
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed = to << in the controller file. I am now getting undefined method 'image' error when loading categories index page. Should I make a further change to the index code?

Comment: Do you have `image` field in your `Product` model? Please explain the data structure related to `image`.

Comment: Yes, Product model contains image. The image was showing up properly when it was calling the last item in the array. But as soon as I changed to the <<, then image became an error on that call in the index file. There are no empty image values or any other empty values in the Product db.

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing to take. I am still getting the undefined method image error. I tried removing take altogether, same error. Any idea?

Comment: Marked this as right answer since it fixed the array assignment problem. I'm still working on the image method error as it seems like a separate issue.